# Memory allocation failed, aborting process.

Tags: apache-2.4

What can be the cause for this error? Here is my full log from the time that my VM crashed.

The machine runs rails but the DB is on a different machine, so no special load should be on the VM itself.

```
App 59191 stdout:
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[ W 2018-01-21 14:42:43.3651 4562/T8 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 1-6207] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ N 2018-01-21 14:42:44.4661 4562/Ta age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 16877, application /var/www/html/XXXX
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777743 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59522 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777800 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59523 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777817 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59526 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777833 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59527 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777855 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59528 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777870 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59529 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777886 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59532 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777902 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59533 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777917 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59534 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777933 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59536 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777948 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59537 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777964 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59538 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777983 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59539 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.777999 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59541 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778014 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59542 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778029 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59544 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778055 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59545 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778069 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59546 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778082 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59547 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778096 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59548 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778109 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59549 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:47.778123 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59553 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
App 59586 stdout:
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:48.779988 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59524 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:42:48.780038 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 59540 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
App 59924 stdout:
App 59931 stdout:
[ W 2018-01-21 14:43:43.0161 4562/Ta age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 2-6205] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ N 2018-01-21 14:43:43.8161 4562/Ta age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 17194, application /var/www/html/XXXX
App 60060 stdout:
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.
[ N 2018-01-21 14:53:00.9188 4562/T4 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 60060, application /var/www/html/XXXX
[ W 2018-01-21 14:53:01.8681 4562/Ta age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: [Client 2-6253] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ W 2018-01-21 14:53:01.8691 4562/T3 age/Cor/App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.cpp:102 ]: Process (pid=59924, group=/var/www/html/XXXX) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
[ N 2018-01-21 14:53:01.8692 4562/T3 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 59924, application /var/www/html/XXXX
[Sun Jan 21 14:53:06.706284 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 60392 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 21 14:53:06.706343 2018] [core:notice] [pid 37465] AH00051: child pid 60418 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Comment: Is there enough memory?

Comment: I can't tell because at the time of the error I was not able to SSH to the VM. Now, everything is OK. The question is: what can cause memory exahust, if the DB operation runs on a different machine.

Comment: I would start by looking at the list of loaded modules with "apachectl -M" command, third party modules are the usual suspects.

Answer (score 0):

Error `[crit] Memory allocation failed, aborting process.` points to lack of memory. There is same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011386/apache-crash-cannot-allocate-memory) on Stack Overflow with good answer.

You could add additional RAM, if it's not possible, add swap or change Apache configuration.